# if condition is not executing in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'am fetching VM's data like name and VMhost from scvmm and storing into a variable $a

i have VM name ex: win10-jde I want to get the win10-jde name and vmhost details by using if statement it is failing any help

```
$b = "win10-jde"
$a = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Select-Object name, vmhost

if ($b -match $a){
    Write-Output "$b"
}
```

`$a` output is:

```
PS C:\Users\scvmmadmin> $a

Name                                       VMHost                
----                                      ------                
ks-finaltest                       slcae661.us.oracle.com

slc12vbv                           slcaf782.us.oracle.com
slc12vbw                           slcap322.us.oracle.com
iSCSItestK-4                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12uzz                           slcae661.us.oracle.com
slc12uzs                           slcae661.us.oracle.com
Test_Stage01                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12vbi                           slcae662.us.oracle.com
slc12vca                           slcaf782.us.oracle.com
slc12vaa                           slcae660.us.oracle.com
slc12vau                           slcap323.us.oracle.com
slc12uzu                           slcae661.us.oracle.com
slc12vbz                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12uys                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
1511Test_01                        slcae662.us.oracle.com
slc12vbk                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vbq                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vbm                           slcap324.us.oracle.com
slc12vat                           slcap322.us.oracle.com
iSCSITestG-2                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12uyx                           slcap323.us.oracle.com
slc12vbu                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vcb                           slcae662.us.oracle.com
slc12vas                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12uyl                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
Win2016-JDE                        slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vab                           slcae660.us.oracle.com
slc12vac                           slcap323.us.oracle.com
Win10JDE-Bare                      slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vcc                           slcaf782.us.oracle.com
JOuten-WorkStation (Do Not Delete) slcap322.us.oracle.com
Win10-JDE                          slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12uyw                           slcaf782.us.oracle.com
slc12uza                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12vag                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12uyv                           slcae662.us.oracle.com
slc12uyt                           slcap322.us.oracle.com
Win10JDE-Bare                      slcac038.us.oracle.com
iSCSItestD-3                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12vax-original                  slcap322.us.oracle.com
2012x64Test                        slcaf782.us.oracle.com
slc12uyu                           slcaf782.us.oracle.com
slc12vbf                           slcap324.us.oracle.com
iSCSItestK-2                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
iSCSItestF-1                       slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12vas                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
Clone_Win2012R2BareOS-May-2017     slcae212.us.oracle.com
slc12vao                           slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12uzb                           slcap322.us.oracle.com
slc12var                           slcae212.us.oracle.com
1511Test_02                        slcae212.us.oracle.com
Win10-JDE                          slcac038.us.oracle.com
slc12vbl                           slcae662.us.oracle.com
```

Comment: `$b` will *never* match `win10-jde` - `$b` is the entire object, with all of the individual rows/columns so to speak.  However, the `Name` property, *within $b*, looks like it may be what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you meant `if($a.Name -match $b){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the object containing the VM details through a foreach loop. And, I would use -eq instead of -match as -match is used for matching regular expressions. More on that below... Try something like this:

```
$b = "win10-jde"
$VMs = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Select-Object name, vmhost

ForEach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    $Name = $VM.Name
    $VMHost = $VM.vmhost

    if ($b -eq $Name)
    {
        Write-Output "$VM"
    }
}
```

Now, the -match operator. One variable will "match" another variable if it is equal to or *contained in* the variable to which it is being compared. E.G. "Blue" will match "Blue Whales".  The comparison operator -eq requires one variable be the same as the variable it is being compared to in order for the comparison to be true.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs and below mentioned code is working for me as expected.

$b = "win10-jde"
$VMs = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Select-Object name, vmhost

ForEach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    $Name = $VM.Name
    $VMHost = $VM.vmhost

    if ($b -eq $Name)
    {
        Write-Output "$Name,$VMHost" 
    }
}

output from console:

Win10-JDE,slcac038.us.oracle.com
Win10-JDE,slcac038.us.oracle.com

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad it's working for you. If my post helped, please up-vote! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to compare string `$b` with an object `$a`, which will never return `true`. All you need to do is compare `$b` with `$a.name`. Please change your code like this.

```
$b = "win10-jde"
$a = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Select-Object name, vmhost
foreach($vm in $a)
{    
    if ($b -eq $vm.name)
    {
        Write-Output "$vm"
    }
}
```